# Explaination of this output

Tags: c++, output, increment

```
int j=5;
std::cout << ++j <<" " << j++ <<" "<< ++j;
```

Why does this program give the following output:

> `8 6 8`

Comment: What were you expecting instead, and why?

Comment: (Yes, that one is tagged C, but it's the same thing in C++.)

Comment: i think it should be 6 6 8

Comment: Since each function call is a sequence point, is there actually undefined behavior here?